# How to parse SOAP XML with prefixes with jsoup?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, soap, jsoup

This is a sample XML.

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<env:Header/>
<env:Body>
    <ns0:NotifyRequest xmlns:ns3='http://dummyurl.com'>
        <PartTotal>10</PartTotal>
        <PartNo>2</PartNo>
    </ns0:NotifyRequest>
</env:Body>
```

My server accepts these requests and this is parsed via Jsoup. I get the element by tag "ns0:NotifyRequest" then look for sub elements.

My problem is; when the prefix changes, my parser fails because the element tag "ns0:NotifyRequest" is written hard-coded, it gives an error when received XML is like "ns3:NotifyRequest".

Is there a way to ignore this prefix and get the NotifyRequest element? I know I can get the inner elements not directly from their 1st level upper element. (I mean I can use BodyElement.getElementsByTag("PartTotal") instead of NotifyRequestElement.getElementsByTag("PartTotal"), they do the same job) But I want to use regex or something and ignore that random prefix and get the NotifyRequest element.

Comment: According to documentation using `.select("*|NotifyRequest")` should work, but quick test shows that there might be an issue when combining with xml parser.

Comment: As Luk mentioned, it doesn't seem like JSoup is able to handle the wildcard for namespace. Since this is XML anyways, have you looked into some of the XML parsers Java offers?